# Partial id match and merge multiple to one

Tags: awk, sed, match

I have two files, File1 and File2. File1 has 6000 rows and file2 has 3000 rows. I want to match the ids and merge the files based on matches, which is simple. But, the ids in file1 and file2 only match partially. Have a look at the files. For every id (row) in file2 there must be two matching ids (rows) in file 1. Also, not all the ids in file2 are present in file1. I had tried awk but didn't get the desired output.

File1

```
1_A01_A
1_A01_B
2_B03_A
2_B03_B
1_A02_A
1_A02_B
2_B04_A
2_B04_B
1_A03_A
1_A03_B
2_B05_A
2_B05_B
1_A04_A
1_A04_B
2_B06_A
2_B06_B
1_A06_A
1_A06_B
2_B07_A
2_B07_B
1_A07_A
1_A07_B
2_B08_A
2_B08_B
9_F10_A
9_F10_B
12_D08_A
12_D08_B
5505744243493_F09.CEL_A_A
5505744243493_F09.CEL_B_B
```

File2

```
1_A01   14
2_B03   13
1_A02   4
2_B04   14
1_A03   11
2_B05   8
1_A04   18
2_B06   15
1_A06   10
2_B07   4
1_A07   8
2_B08   22
1_A08   5
2_B09   15
1_A09   20
2_B10   17
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk -F"   " 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}{for(i in a){if($1~i){print $1"   "a[i];next}}}' file1.txt file2.txt`

> FNR==NR will be true while awk reads file 1 and false when it reads file 2. The part of code starting from {for(i in a} .. will be executed for file 2. $1~i looks for Like condition and then for relevant matches the output is printed.
>
> **by mistake I have used different file notations. My file1.txt contains the content of file2.txt in the problem statement and vise versa**
>
> **Output**
> 1_A01_A|14
> 1_A01_B|14
> 2_B03_A|13
> 2_B03_B|13
> 1_A02_A|4
> 1_A02_B|4
> 2_B04_A|14
> 2_B04_B|14
> 1_A03_A|11
> 1_A03_B|11
> 2_B05_A|8
> 2_B05_B|8
> 1_A04_A|18
> 1_A04_B|18
> 2_B06_A|15
> 2_B06_B|15
> 1_A06_A|10
> 1_A06_B|10
> 2_B07_A|4
> 2_B07_B|4
> 1_A07_A|8
> 1_A07_B|8
> 2_B08_A|22
> 2_B08_B|22

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78094/discussion-on-answer-by-dipak-partial-id-match-and-merge-multiple-to-one).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's|^(\S+)(\s+\S+)$|s/^\1.*/\&\2/p|' file2 | sed -nf - file1
```

This creates a sed script from `file2` and then runs it against the data in `file1`.

N.B. The order of either file is unimportant and `file1` is processed only once.

Comment: No luck. Running into error, sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command